# how to get time like (1 - 2 pm) or (2 - 3 pm)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have tried to show the current date and time.for current date and time is working well,Here is my code:

```
NSDate *currDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM YYYY  hh:mm a"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currDate];

    _dateLabel.text=dateString;
```

What i need is .I need to show my time like:

for example now this question posted time is `1:42pm`. I want like this:

**1 - 2 pm**

But for above code i am getting : `1:42 pm`. I need like this:

```
1 - 2 pm
```

Please help me how to do that 1 hour slot.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (NSString *)dateString {
    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitHour fromDate:currentDate];
    NSInteger hour = [components hour];
    NSInteger nextHour = [components hour] + 1;
    NSString *nextHourDateString = @"";
    if (nextHour == 24) {
        nextHour = 0;
        NSTimeInterval oneHour = 60 * 60;
        NSDate *nextHourDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:oneHour sinceDate:currentDate];
        nextHourDateString = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:nextHourDate] stringByAppendingString:@" "];
    }
    NSString *hourSuffix = hour > 12 ? @" pm" : @" am";
    NSString *nextHourSuffix = nextHour > 12 ? @" pm" : @" am";
    if ([hourSuffix isEqualToString:nextHourSuffix]) {
        hourSuffix = @"";
    }
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %ti%@ - %@%ti%@",
                                      dateString,
                                      [self hourInTwelveHourFormat:hour],
                                      hourSuffix,
                                      nextHourDateString,
                                      [self hourInTwelveHourFormat:nextHour],
                                      nextHourSuffix];;
}

- (NSInteger)hourInTwelveHourFormat:(NSInteger)hour {
    if (hour > 12) {
        hour -= 12;
    }
    return hour;
}
```

Comment: Yes, forgot about pm, I edited my answer. Also you should handle a case 11 pm - 0 am.

Comment: its possible to show in my code. Because i need both day and date in single line

Comment: like : " 15 FEB 2016 2 - 3 PM "

Comment: In my code i showed " date month year timing". So i need like this " 15 FEB 2016 2 - 3PM"

Comment: just add your date (15 FEB 2016) in the beginning

Comment: LIKE THIS dd MMM YYYY ??

Comment: NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dd MMM YYYY %ti - %ti %@", hour % 12, (hour + 1) % 12, hour > 12? @"pm" : @"am"];

Comment: By default i need to show the today's date month year with timing. With you code how can i add all in single line

Comment: Updated my answer again

Comment: @VladimirKravchenko well explained.